# Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of "outer-product" matrix $M_{(ij),(pq)} = A_{i,p} B_{j,q}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products, kronecker-product

I have a matrix $M$ of the form $M_{(ij),(pq)} = A_{i,p} B_{j,q}$, where $A,B$ are two square matrices. I need to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$.

If $\alpha, u$ and $\beta, v$ are an eigenvalue/eigenvector pair for $A$ and $B$, respectively, then it is easy to see that the vector $w_{(ij)} = u_i v_j$ is an eigenvector of $M$ with eigenvalue $\alpha\beta$.

Are all eigenvalue/eigenvectors of $M$ of this form?

Comment: Don't know what $M_{(ij),(pq)}$ means. Is $ij$ supposed to be a product of $i$ times $j$? If so is the right hand side a sum over pairs $(i,j)$ with the same product?

Comment: @Ben $(ij)$ denotes a single index in a product space.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then if $A\in End(V), B\in End(W)$ then $M \in End(V\otimes W)$ define by $M(v\otimes w) = Av\otimes Bw$

Comment: I think so, except I'm not sure what product operator you are using here? I am sure it's standard notation, but can you provide a wikipedia link or something? I think my question has an answer out there I just didn't search with the correct keywords.

Comment: tensor product of vector spaces. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: Thanks. For future reference, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Abstract_properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because if you have pairs $v_1,v_2$ and $u_1,u_2$ of independent eigenvectors with the same eigenvalues or at least $\alpha_1\beta_1 = \alpha_2\beta_2$ then $$u_1\otimes v_1 + u_2\otimes v_2$$ is an $\alpha\beta$ eigenvector as well but is not a pure tensor.

On the otherhand it is in the span of eigenvectors of the form which you mentioned, and so long as your field is algebraically closed so that there are bases of eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$, then the product of the bases gives a basis of eigenvectors for $M$.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I expected intuitively. I was missing the precise notation for it.

Comment: No problem (learning tensor notation is absolutely worth it!)